# Django piston, doesn't work, some TypRerror

Tags: django, django-piston

Where could be the error?

My code is pretty usual.

<del>http://pastebin.com/cFfNNGm5</del>  http://wklej.org/id/518600/ < - This is it

And some my code:

http://wklej.org/id/518601/

Without imports

Comment: Please post traceback and some code here, pastebin entries time out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you added your authentication inappropriately: `resource.Resource(... authentication=MyAuthenticationClass)` instead of `resource.Resource(..., authentication=MyAuthenticationClass())`. Types don't match (a `type` instead of its instance), hence the whole problem.